# Custom npm script in ecosystem.config.js

Tags: node.js, npm, pm2

To start a custom npm script `start` with pm2 as a one-time process, I'd run `pm2 start npm -- start`, and to move this into the `ecosystem.config.js` file, my app would be configured as

```
...
script: 'npm',
args: 'start',
...
```

But things fall apart when instead of start, I need to run the `dev` script, like you would in `npm run dev`. I've tried

```
...
script: 'npm run dev',
...
```

```
...
script: 'npm',
args: 'run dev',
...
```

and

```
...
script: 'npm',
args: 'dev',
...
```

with no luck so far. Could I be missing something, or is there an entirely different approach?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using reactJs + nextJs and I'm also facing the same issue with `ecosystem.config.js` configuration in PM2, but you can use the following command it's working for me.

```
pm2 start "npm run dev" --name YOUR_APP_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

you missing `cwd` field, the directory from which your app will be launched

```
...
name: 'app',
script: 'npm',
cwd: '/var/www/html/app',
args: 'run develop',
...
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck